# Counting how many times a certain char appears in a string before any other char appears

Tags: c#

I have many strings. Each string is prepended with at least 1 `$`. What is the best way to loop through the chars of each string to count how many `$`'s there are per string.

eg:

```
"$hello" - 1
"$$hello" - 2
"$$h$ello" - 2
```

Answer (score 122):

You could use the Count method

```
var count = mystring.Count(x => x == '$')
```

Comment: Is this not better (simpler and/or faster) than using TakeWhile()?

Comment: No because, as Jon points out in his comment thread, this counts all `$` and not just the leading ones.

Comment: In case it's not obvious, you will need to add a "using System.Linq;" to your class file, or you'll get the 'string has no definition for Count' error.

Answer (score 37):

```
int count = myString.TakeWhile(c => c == '$').Count();
```

And without LINQ

```
int count = 0;
while(count < myString.Length && myString[count] == '$') count++;
```

Comment: you're missing the declaration for `i` and also incrementing it in your `while` loop. A `for` loop might make things tidier.

Comment: @Ahmad my fault, had an i counter at first, didn't change everything. Still like the while though.

Comment: oh now I see what you were going for. That works, no need for the `for` loop :)

Comment: Excellent. Thanks Yuriy.
I just wanted to point out the importance of using '$' and not "$"... ;)

Comment: It looks as though this will only get the number of '$' chars that the string starts with, not the total number of occurrences.

Comment: @Shaggy The question is confusing. If you look at the example or the title, I've answered it, if you read the description I'm wrong.

Comment: Is using Count(x => x == '$') not better (simpler and/or faster) than using TakeWhile(x => x == '$').Count()?

Comment: @Jimmy those are two different answers. TakeWhile gets how many $ it start with while Count will take the total.

Answer (score 23):

The simplest approach would be to use LINQ:

```
var count = text.TakeWhile(c => c == '$').Count();
```

There are certainly more efficient approaches, but that's probably the simplest.

Comment: Hey jon, this is sort of a offtopic question but you seem to know a lot:
In what situation would one not use linq? I'm a noobie programmer and I was wondering because (as in this context) I think it would be the best way.?

Comment: @Levisaxos: If you really needed the fastest possible performance, there are better alternatives. Or if you're working on .NET 2 and don't need LINQ elsewhere. That's just talking about this case though - there are plenty of places where you *can* use LINQ, but it actually makes the code more complicated instead of simpler.

Comment: How about var count = text.Count(t => t == '$');

Comment: @SteveChadbourne: No, that would just count the number of dollars in total.

Answer (score 12):

You could do this, it doesn't require LINQ, but it's not the best way to do it(since you make split the whole string and put it in an array and just pick the length of it, you could better just do a `while` loop and check every character), but it works.

```
int count = test.Split('$').Length - 1;
```

Comment: For me the best solution in terms of computation time

Answer (score 9):

```
var str ="hello";
str.Where(c => c == 'l').Count()  // 2
```

Comment: This enumerates the string twice, whereas str.Count(c => c == 'l'); will only enumerate the string once. And that is basically the same answer as the accepted one.

Comment: @oopbase That's not true. Because Linq is based on yielding, enumeration will happen only once.

Answer (score 7):

```
int count = yourText.Length - yourText.TrimStart('$').Length;
```

Comment: Though the OP is somewhat ambiguous in regard to stating "to count how many $'s there are per string." Does he mean how many *in* the string, or how many at the beginning of the string? (Though he does show a count of 2 in the third example.)

Answer (score 5):

```
int count = Regex.Matches(myString,"$").Count;
```

Comment: This will count all occurrences of '$', not just the ones at the beginning.  From the OP's example, this would fail the third test case.

Comment: @Darthfett, I don't see how? He said each string is prepended with one `$` and he wants to know how many after that, so this is the correct answer.

Comment: @KyloRen When I wrote the comment, it seemed clear to me that the question was asking how many `$` appear at the *beginning* of the string.  Now it is not as clear.

Comment: @Darthfett, looking at the edits, I see what you mean now.

Answer (score 5):

```
public static int GetHowManyTimeOccurenceCharInString(string text, char c)
{
    int count = 0;
    foreach(char ch in text)
    {
        if(ch.Equals(c))
        {
            count++;
        }

    }
    return count;
}
```

Comment: I'm guessing here, but I suspect this is actually significantly more efficient than using LINQ (or Regex). I'd also be curious if you replaced the foreach loop with an iterator (`for (int i=0; i<text.Length; ++i)`), replacing `ch` with `text[i]`, if that would even crank up the efficiency just a little bit.

Answer (score 2):

just a simple answer:

```
    public static int CountChars(string myString, char myChar)
    {
        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < myString.Length; i++)
        {
            if (myString[i] == myChar) ++count;
        }
        return count;
    }
```

Cheers! - Rick

Answer (score 1):

This is a similar Solution to find how many email addresses included in a string. This way is more efficient`

```
int count = 0;
foreach (char c in email.Trim())
    if (c == '@') count++;
```

Answer (score 1):

One approach you could take is the following method:

```
// Counts how many of a certain character occurs in the given string
public static int CharCountInString(char chr, string str)
{
    return str.Split(chr).Length-1;
}
```

As per the parameters this method returns the count of a specific character within a specific string.

This method works by splitting the string into an array by the specified character and then returning the length of that array -1.

Answer (score 1):

//This code worked for me

```
class CountOfLettersOfString
{
    static void Main()
    {

        Console.WriteLine("Enter string to check count of letters");
        string name = Console.ReadLine();

        //Method1
        char[] testedalphabets = new char[26];
        int[] letterCount = new int[26];
        int countTestesd = 0;
        Console.WriteLine($"Given String is:{name}");

        for (int i = 0; i < name.Length - 1; i++)
        {
            int countChar = 1;

            bool isCharTested = false;

            for (int j = 0; j < testedalphabets.Length - 1; j++)
            {
                if (name[i] == testedalphabets[j])
                {
                    isCharTested = true;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (!isCharTested)
            {
                testedalphabets[countTestesd] = name[i];

                for (int k = i + 1; k < name.Length - 1; k++)
                {
                    if (name[i] == name[k])
                    {
                        countChar++;
                    }
                }
                letterCount[countTestesd] = countChar;
                countTestesd++;

            }
            else
            {
                continue;
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < testedalphabets.Length - 1; i++)
        {
            if (!char.IsLetter(testedalphabets[i]))
            {
                continue;
            }
            Console.WriteLine($"{testedalphabets[i]}-{letterCount[i]}");
        }


        //Method2
        var g = from c in name.ToLower().ToCharArray() // make sure that L and l are the same eg
                group c by c into m
                select new { Key = m.Key, Count = m.Count() };

        foreach (var item in g)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Character:{0} Appears {1} times", item.Key.ToString(), item.Count));
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```