# How to check how much char space in 1 string

Tags: java, string, char

Lets say I have a string with some text:

```
String str="Hello My Name Is Help!"
```

And I want to check how much space chars I have in the following `String str`. I would like a make a method that takes that following string and returns the number of `whitespaces` in that string. For example if I name my method `getNumberOfWhiteSpaces(String str)` and call it a I should get back the number of whitespaces.

```
if( getNumberOfWhiteSpaces(String str) > 3)
     System.out.println("There are more then 3 spaces in this string");

public int getNumberOfWhiteSpaces(String str) {
  ....
  return some number
}
```

Comment: It's not that clear to me what you want to achieve. Can you give some example inputs with the desired output?

Comment: Check this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5340564/counting-how-many-times-a-certain-char-appears-in-a-string-before-any-other-char

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution is to use `replaceAll` to replace all non space (`[^\s]`) with empty and check the length of result output :

```
if (str.replaceAll("[^\\s]", "").length() > 3) {...}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
String str="Hello My Name Is Help!";
int spaces = str.length() - str.replace(" ", "").length();
if(spaces > 3){
    System.out.println("There are more then 3 spaces in this string");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Java 8 way could be:

```
s.chars().filter(Character::isWhitespace).count()
```

which will give you the number of *white space* in the string `s`. You can also use `isSpaceChar`.